# How to keep the RunAsync() method running in the background without calling Wait()?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, backgroundworker

Trying to advance from using BackgroundWorker to Task, I am getting confused on how to keep the background job running without calling Wait().

This is the background job (simplified):

```
    private async Task RunAsync()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await TheHttpClient.GetAsync(Path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            textBox_Response.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

When the Send button is clicked, the above code should run, but because the background code has more than one `await` async calls, I guess that there are several `Wait()` calls needed:

```
    private void button_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = RunAsync();
        while (!t.IsCompleted)
        {
            t.Wait();
        }
    }
```

But this would block the GUI during the entire processing time of the background job.

How can I start the background job and return immediately from the button click handler, while allowing the background job to run all async calls?

I know how to achieve this with the BackgroundWorker, should I not use a Task here?

Comment: Make button_send_click event async and use await intead of wait... Btw you dont need multiple waits...

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Without await I could not assign the output of GetAsync() to response. Similar for the second await.

Comment: I meant multiple waits inside event.... You used while loop which is not necessary.

Comment: @Roland: I have a [blog series contrasting how to do things with BGW and with `Task.Run` (and showing why `Task.Run` is superior in every case)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary I already found your blog. But my little case in this question is for me enough evidence that `Task` is a big improvement over `BackgroundWorker`, which, by the way, I find a a big improvement over `Thread` in most cases. But for Task you need to upgrade to .Net 4, while we still maintain projects in .Net 3.5, or even .Net CF!

Comment: @Roland: `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` will get you `TaskEx.Run` on .NET 4. The older platforms, though, ouch...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event handlers are the only place you are allowed to do `async void`, what you do is make the event handler async and await it there

```
private async void button_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await RunAsync();

    //Do code here that needs to run after RunAsync has finished.
}
```

Comment: Ok, I remember having read about async event handler. I will try this.

Comment: Looks really good but I could only test the first await. When my project gets further along, I will be able to test if it passes the second await in RunAsync(). For now I will accept this answer as working!

Comment: If you want to test it replace the 2nd await with a `await Task.Delay(1000);` that will give it a 1 second pause as if `ReadAsStringAsync()` took one second to complete. `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        { await Task.Delay(1000);
            textBox_Response.Text = "Fake Data";
        }`

Comment: Good method! multiple awaits handled just like I want it. Thanks! Also now definitely sold to Task.

Answer (score 2):

Quite often people think that async await is an asynchronous process performed by several threads, but in fact it is all done by one thread, unless you start a new thread using Task.Run or similar functions.

In [this interview](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) (somewhere in the middle. Search for async) Eric Lippert compared the async-await by the works of a cook in a restaurant. If he is toasting bread, he could wait for the bread to be ready before boiling the eggs, OR he could start boiling eggs and get back to the bread afterwards. It looks like the cook is doing two things at the time, but in fact he is only doing one thing, and whenever he has to wait for something he starts looking around to see if he can do other things.

If your one-and-only thread calls an asynchronous function, without awaiting for it. Your one-and-only thread starts executing that function until he sees an await. If he sees one, he doesn't wait until the async function completes, instead he remembers where he was awaiting and goes up in his call stack to see if his caller has something else to do (== is not awaiting). The caller can do the next statements until he meets an await. In that case control is given back up the call stack to the caller until he awaits etc. If your one-and-only thread is awaiting in all functions in the call stack control is given back to the first await. When that is finished your thread starts doing the statements after the await until he meets another await, or until the function is finished.

You can be certain that every async function has an await somewhere. If there is no await it is not meaningful to create it as an async function. In fact your compiler will warn you if you forgot to await somewhere in your async function.

In your example, you can expect an error, or at least a warning that you forgot to declare your button_send_click async. Without this the procedure can't await.

But after you've declared it async, and the button is pressed, your GUI-thread will call RunAsync where it will enter function TheHttpClient.GetAsync.

Inside this function is an await ReadAsStringAsync, and because ReadAsStringAsync is declared async, we can be certain that that function has an await in it. As soon as this await is met, control is given back to your TheHttpClient.GetAsync. This function would be free to perform the next statement if it didn't await. An example would be like this:

```
private async Task RunAsync()
{
    var responseTask = TheHttpClient.GetAsync(Path);
    // because no await, your thread will do the following as soon as GetAsync encounters await:
    DoSomethingUseFul();

    // once your procedure has nothing useful to do anymore
    // or it needs the result of the responseTask it can await:
    var response = await responseTask;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    ...
```

The await is after DoSomethingUseful(). Therefore, the function can't continue. Instead of doing nothing until responseTask is finished, control is given back to the caller: button_send_click. If that function wasn't await it would be free to do other things. But since the button_send_click is awaiting control is given back to the caller: your UI is free to do other things.

**But remember: it is always the one-and-only cook who makes your breakfast** Your thread can do only one thing at a time

The advantage is that you won't run into difficulties you have with multiple threads. The disadvantage is that as long as your thread doesn't meet an await, it is too busy to do other things.

If you need to do some lengthy calculation while you don't want to be busy doing the calculation you can start a separate thread doing this calculation. This gives your thread time to do other things, like keeping the UI responsive until it needs the results of the calculations:

```
private async void Button1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    var taskLengthyCalculation = Task.Run( () => DoLengthyCalculation(...));
    // while a different thread is doing calculations
    // I am free to do other things:
    var taskRunAsync = RunAsync();
    // still no await, when my thread has to await in RunAsync,
    // the next statement:
    DoSomethingUseful();
    var result = await taskRunAsync();
    var resultLengthyCalculation = await taskLengthyCalculation;
```